# Drop down list in ASP MVC C# LiNQ

Tags: c#

This code shows a list of customer names in a drop down that have orders that are marked as samples.  However, as there are multiple orders for the same customer, the list shows the same customer name serval times.  How do I adjust the code to group by CustomerID please?

```
protected void FetchCustomerList()
        {
            ViewData["Customers"] = (from c in _stockEntities.tblAddresses
                                     join orders in _stockEntities.tblOrders on c.AddressID equals  orders.CustomerID
                                     where orders.Sample != 0
                                     orderby c.AName
                                     select c);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you join if you just want addresses with orders? You can use:

```
var customersWithOrders = _stockEntities.tblAddresses
    .Where(c => _stockEntities.tblOrders
        .Any(o => c.AddressID == o.CustomerID && o.Sample != 0))
    .OrderBy(c => c.AName);
```

I guess that will be translated to an efficient `EXISTS` query.

Comment: Thank you for the code.  On trying it, I get customers listed correctly but it lists some customers that have orders that are not maked as sample.

Comment: @CrazyIvan: have you really used my code? `c.AddressID == o.CustomerID && o.Sample != 0`

Comment: Yes like this:          ViewData["Customers"] = _stockEntities.tblAddresses
            .Where(c => _stockEntities.tblOrders.Any(o => c.AddressID == o.CustomerID && o.Sample != 0))
            .OrderBy(c => c.AName);

Comment: @CrazyIvan: then you should only get customers which have at least one order with `Sample!=0`. Maybe your business logic is different, then you have to explain it.

Comment: Tim, thank you for your help with this.  Correct, the business logic has Orders that are samples marked with a -1 so I have amended o.Sample == -1.  That now only lists customers in the dropdown that have orders that are marked as samples.